# Dart best practice to return null from RangeError (index)

Tags: dart

What is the best practice to return null for:

> Unhandled exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2

My code:

```
late final int? element;
try {
  element = l[index];
} catch(e) {
  element = null;
}
```

Looking for a shorter, one-liner solution.

Something like:

```
final element = l[index] ?? null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice for errors is to not throw them.

In this case, I'd do:

```dart
final T? element = (index >= 0 && index < l.length) ? l[index] : null;
```

No need for `late`, not throwing or catching errors.

If an error does get thrown, it's probably a *real* error in the program.
If you catch and ignore errors that you expect, you risk also catching errors you didn't expect, and hiding real problems. That's the real reason catching errors as part of "normal control flow" is frowned upon, not just because less efficient. Which it also is.
And it's why you should always throw (and document) precise types of exceptions from an API, so that the user can do precise catches.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use the list extensions package from the Dart team.

First of all, you need to import the package:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

Then you can get the element at a given index or null if the index is out of range.

```
final element = list.elementAtOrNull(index);
```

The underlying code is similar to Irn's answer, except that a negative index is not allowed and will raise an exception. Semantically, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer can satisfy you. :)

```
final int? element = (index == null || index.clamp(0,l.length - 1) != index) ? null : l[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [extension method](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) :

**myextension.dart** :

```
  extension NullableList<T> on List<T> {
      T? nullable(int index){
        T? element;
        try {
          element = this[index];
        } catch(_) {
        }
        return element;
      }
    }
```

use it :

**homepage.dart** :

```
List<int> l = [1];
  int? result = l.nullable(3);
  print(result); //--> null
  print(l.nullable(0)); //--> 1
```

Comment: `        } catch(_) {
        }`  ---- empty catch is a code smell.  catch only what you are willing to handle, and let the rest flow upward.